# how does operator of type "operator class()" works

Tags: c++

Im trying to figure how such an operator works:
I found nothing about it searching the web...
Is it used as a casting between types?
Why do I need the = operator (in line a = b) instead of a b ?
What other uses does it have?
thanks

```
class A{
   int a;
}; 

class B{
   int b;
   operator A() { return A(); }
};

int main(){
   A a;
   B b;
   a = b;
   return 0; 

}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator might be a start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking at is a [user defined conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator). IT has plenty of uses, for example. Consider a smart pointer:

```
class SmartPointer {
    // Constructor destructor, operator* and & etc ..
}
```

If it were a raw pointer, we could check for it being `nullptr` like this:

```
if (ptr) {
    ptr->do_something();
}
```

So how can we achieve the same with a smart pointer? We can define `operator bool`.

Another example could be something like a units class:

```
class Meters {
    ...
}
```

What if we want to be able to achieve this:

```
void some_operation(double meters);
Meters m{10};
some_operation(m);
```

Well we can define a conversion operator:

```
Meters::operator double() {
    return _meters;
}
```

Remember when you are looking into this to check if you need the [`explicit` specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit), it is likely that you will want to use this for most conversions.

Comment: `Meters` to `Centimeters` isn't a great example, because one could add a constructor to `Centimeters`.  A better example might be something converting to a `std::pair` or `std::string`, where you can't add new constructors.